# Wrong output when searching in a rotated array with duplicates

Tags: python

While testing the output I found an error in my output. With arr2 and x = 3 as my input, the value mid is 4 during the last recursive call, as it should be. However, instead of returning mid, it instead skips the if statement and returns False at the end. Does anyone [enter image description here][1]see what I did wrong here? Thank you

```
class rotatedArraySearch:
    #similar to binary search
    def rotatedAS(self,arr,x,low,high):
        mid = (low + high)/2
        print mid
        if x == arr[mid]: return mid

        if low > high: return False

        #check which side is ordered properly
        if arr[low] < arr[mid]:
            #if the left side is ordered properly, check if it is in the left side, if not search right
            if x >= arr[low] and x < arr[mid]: return self.rotatedAS(arr,x,low,mid-1)


            else: return self.rotatedAS(arr,x,mid+1,high)

        elif arr[mid] < arr[low]:
            #same for right side
            if x > arr[mid] and arr <= arr[high]: return self.rotatedAS(arr,x,mid+1,high)


            else: return self.rotatedAS(arr,x,low,mid-1)

        #if there are duplicate values the order is not known, check both sides
        elif arr[low] == arr[mid]:
            if arr[mid] != arr[high]: return self.rotatedAS(arr,mid+1,high,x)


            else:
                result = self.rotatedAS(arr,low,mid-1,x)
                if(result == False): return self.rotatedAS(arr,mid+1,high,x)


                else: return result

        return False
#test
arr = [5,6,7,2,3,4]
arr2 = [2,2,2,2,3,4,1]
ras = rotatedArraySearch()
print ras.rotatedAS(arr2,3,0,len(arr2)-1)
```

Comment: Never post screenshots of code, copy and paste instead.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Sorry about that, pasted it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have messed code in the last `elif` block

> ```
> if arr[mid] != arr[high]: return self.rotatedAS(arr,mid+1,high,x)
> if(result == False): return self.rotatedAS(arr,mid+1,high,x)
> ```
>
> `result = self.rotatedAS(arr,low,mid-1,x)`

Change it to

- `if arr[mid] != arr[high]: return self.rotatedAS(arr,x,mid+1,high)`
- `if(result == False): return self.rotatedAS(arr,x,mid+1,high)`
- `result = self.rotatedAS(arr,x,low,mid-1)`

Please note `x` is search value and you are passing it as high value in last elif loop

Last code block should be:

```
    elif arr[low] == arr[mid]:
        if arr[mid] != arr[high]:
            #Change here
            return self.rotatedAS(arr, x, mid + 1, high)
    else:
        ##Change here
        result = self.rotatedAS(arr,x , low, mid - 1)
        if not result:
        #Change here
            return self.rotatedAS(arr, x, mid + 1, high)
        else:
            return result

    return False
```

#### Output:

```
x=3 mid value=2 at pos 3 
x=3 mid value=4 at pos 5 
x=3 mid value=3 at pos 4 
4
```

Note : tracing

```
print 'x={} mid value={} at pos {} '.format(x, arr[mid], mid)
```